# Best Way to Handle Local Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have the following problem:

I have 2 calendars which both need to create local notifications (which will fire 5 min before each event). In the settings the user has the ability to turn notifications on or off for either calendar. If the user was originally using the notifications for both calendars and now wants to only use notifications for one calendar, how can I delete only the notifications in one calendar?

I think I have 3 options:

1. Running `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` and then add back all the ones in the other calendar (this will probably be harder than it sounds).
2. Storing arrays of created notifications in something like the user defaults and then looping through the arrays calling: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];`
3. Subclassing `UILocalNotification` and adding some field which will allow me to sort the notifications. Then maybe I could call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` and loop through that checking that field and deleting those which are necessary.

Is there a standard way of doing this? I think the third is probably the easiest, but I'm  not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` has a standard `userInfo` property that is a `NSDictionary` of arbitrary values as long as the keys are valid property-list types. If you subclass `UILocalNotification`, you must use that dictionary as the backing store for additional properties or fields you wish to persist. And to be able to use your subclass, you will need an initialization method that will copy the properties from the base class to your subclass.

```
#define kNoficationCalendarName NSStringFromSelector(@selector(calendarName))

@interface XXLocalNotification : UILocalNotification

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * calendarName;

- (instancetype)initWithLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;

@end

@implementation XXLocalNotification

- (instancetype)initWithLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        //Copy properties
        self.alertAction = notification.alertAction;
        self.alertBody = notification.alertBody;
        self.alertLaunchImage = notification.alertLaunchImage;
        self.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber;
        self.fireDate = notification.fireDate;
        self.hasAction = notification.hasAction;
        self.repeatCalendar = notification.repeatCalendar;
        self.repeatInterval = notification.repeatInterval;
        self.soundName = notification.soundName;
        self.timeZone = notification.timeZone;
        self.userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setCalendarName:(NSString *)calendarName
{
    NSMutableDictionary * userInfo = [[self userInfo] mutableCopy];
    [userInfo setValue:calendarName
                forKey:kNoficationCalendarName];
}
- (NSString *)calendarName
{
    return [[self userInfo] valueForKey:kNoficationCalendarName];
}

@end
```